# Media Uploader in custom path

Tags: theme-development, css, uploads, media-library

I am creating a CSS generator in my WordPress theme and I want to be able to save custom skins with images as well. My problem is that I have a hierarchy like /skins/custom-skin/images for the uploaded images, but as you know the WordPress Media Uploader puts them in the uploads folder by default, sorted by date.

My question is, can I specify a path to save the image to every time a new image is uploaded?

Comment: Where is the generator being utilized from? A custom admin page? Through a meta box on a post, page or custom post type, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In,

```
Dashboard -> Settings -> Media
```

You can uncheck the,

☑  `Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders`

...and optionally change the path uploads (but this would effect all uploads of course).

Optionally you can hook onto the `upload_dir` filter and change the upload path for a given `post_type`, or for some other given scenario depending upon where and under what condition you are making these uploads.

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'css_upload_dir' );

function css_upload_dir(){

    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $upload = wp_upload_dir();

    if( "post_type" == get_post_type($post_id) ){

        $custom_dir     = '/skins/custom-skin/images';
        $upload['path'] = $upload['basedir'] . $custom_dir;
        $upload['url']  = $upload['baseurl'] . $custom_dir;

        return $upload;
    }
}
```

That ***should*** work, though I've not tested it, so I'm going off the top my head at the moment.

Comment: `return $upload;` after the `if` conditional, otherwise big errors.

Comment: @aifrim edit the answer! ;)

Comment: `function() { .. if(...) {...} return $upload; }` because: what happens if `"post_type" == get_post_type($post_id)` is `FALSE`?